# Use XPATH to find if certain values are not contained in any occurence of a specific node

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<query> 
    <row> 
        <EMPLID>001001</EMPLID>
        <NAME>Smith,Jim</NAME> 
        <DEPT>2929</DEPT>
        <DED_CUR>37.50</DED_CUR> 
    </row>
    <row> 
        <EMPLID>001004</EMPLID>
        <NAME>Green, Bill</NAME> 
        <DEPT>3498</DEPT>
        <DED_CUR>37.50</DED_CUR> 
    </row>
</query>
```

Is there any way using XPATH to say something like

```
If no DEPT node contains 5555 or 7777, then do the following....
```

The purpose would be to do something special if there is no employee on the query in DEPT 5555 or 7777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use = to check if there is a common element in two sequences. I.e to check if there is no one who is in DEPT 5555 or DEPT 7777 (= there is no one in DEPT 5555 and no one in DEPT 7777):

```
if (not(//DEPT = ("5555",  "7777"))) then ...
```

Or, if you want to check, if there is no one in DEPT 5555 or no one in DEPT 7777:

```
if (not(//DEPT[. = "5555"]) or not(//DEPT[. = "7777"])) then ...
```

Or equivalent, and possibly faster:

```
if (count(distinct-values(//DEPT[. = ("5555", "7777")])) < 2) then ...
```

Comment: This was very helpful, the "not" functionality worked the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count()` to find the number of occurances of `DEPT` nodes that do match a certain value (in this example `7777` and `5555`)

```
count(//DEPT[text() != '7777' and text() != '5555'])
```

Like in your example, you may also use conditions to react to this result within XPath

```
if (count(//DEPT[text() != '7777' and text() != '5555']) > 0) then ('Found at least one') else ('Found none')
```